# Retrieving disk capacity with powershell

Tags: powershell, for-loop, powershell-cmdlet

I made this code to count disk capacity, but when i run it with only the SSD in my laptop i get 0GB. after I insert USB/external space it count the ssd + the USB.

```
$disk = Get-WmiObject Win32_DiskDrive

$capacity = 0;

for($i = 0;$i -lt $disk.Count; $i++){
    $capacity = $capacity + [math]::round(($disk[$i].Size/1GB),2)
}


Write-Host $capacity "GB"
```

This works fine -> `$disk.Size`

Why does it not take the first [0] in my for loop?

Comment: I suspect that SSD does not register in the `Win32_DiskDrive` wmi class since it's not a hard-disk, but that's just a wild guess.  If you're on Win10, I'd suggest just using `Get-Disk`

Comment: I have a single SSD in my laptop and Get-WmiObject Win32_DiskDrive returns the correct information.  try using Get-CimInstance Win32_DiskDrive or Get-Disk as previously suggested

Comment: No idea why it would do that, as said below always use ForEach, it's much better.

Comment: How many disks are in your $disk value? if $disk.size returns a value, I would assume it is only picking up a single disk, which case there wouldn't be a $disk[0]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cannot answer why your `for` loop is failing without observing your environment, but there is almost never a use-case for it.  You should instead opt for a `foreach` loop:

```
$capacity = foreach ($disk in Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_DiskDrive)
{
    [Math]::Round(($disk.Size / 1GB), 2)
}

"$(($capacity | Measure-Object -Sum).Sum)GB"
```

Comment: It's a matter of getting a single object in $disk rather than a collection of them. Something like `$disk = @() ; $disk +=gwmi Win32_DiskDrive` does work but I didn't want to post that as an answer. Using your foreach-approach is the sane way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming Windows 10 since you didn't mention OS and the CMDLETS in Windows 10 are so much better. *See at the bottom for a Windows 7 version.

For disk information, I prefer using Get-PhysicalDisk, like this for example:

```
$DiskInfo = foreach ($disk in Get-PhysicalDisk) {

[string]$name = $disk.FriendlyName
[string]$type = $disk.MediaType
[int]$capacity = $disk.size / 1GB

    [pscustomobject]@{
    "Type"=$type;
    "Name"=$name;
    "Capacity (GB)"=$capacity;
    }

}


$DiskInfo
```

In my environement where I have one SSD and one mechanical HDD, it will return:

```
Name                       Type Capacity (GB)
----                       ---- -------------
SAMSUNG MZ7TY256HDHP-000L7 SSD            238
ST500LX025-1U717D          HDD            466
```

If you wanted information for JUST the SSD for example, you could do this :

```
$DiskInfo = foreach ($disk in Get-PhysicalDisk | Where-Object {$_.MediaType -eq "SSD"} ) {

[string]$name = $disk.FriendlyName
[string]$type = $disk.MediaType
[int]$capacity = $disk.size / 1GB

    [pscustomobject]@{
    "Type"=$type;
    "Name"=$name;
    "Capacity (GB)"=$capacity;
    }

}


$DiskInfo
```

Which returns only the SSD:

```
Type Name                       Capacity (GB)
---- ----                       -------------
SSD  SAMSUNG MZ7TY256HDHP-000L7           238
```

Explanation: Foreach disk connected, store name, media type and capacity in variables. *Divide byte capacity by 1GB to get a better number to look at.
Still in the Foreach, create a custom object at every iteration containing the 3 variables.

All put together, you can then output your variable DiskInfo which contains all the objects.

If on Windows 7, media type isn't available so you can't use it. Instead you can do:

```
$DiskInfo = foreach ($disk in Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_DiskDrive) {

[string]$name = $disk.model
[int]$capacity = $disk.size / 1GB

    [pscustomobject]@{
    "Name"=$name;
    "Capacity (GB)"=$capacity;
    }

}


$DiskInfo
```

Which will return something like:

```
Name                       Capacity (GB)
----                       -------------
SAMSUNG MZ7TY256HDHP-000L7           238
ST500LX025-1U717D                    466
```

Comment: Your foreach loop is redundant. You can just set the section you need inside the pscustomobject. `"type"=$disk.mediatype` you should be able to put [string] before disk to sprecify output as a strong. Or use the string method.

Comment: Yeah but I love declearing variables first ;) I know it's more lines of code but to me it's clearer when read. Started writing like this to counter the syntax abuse sometimes where you end up with strings like this for example : $($($ABC.$DEF.GHI)..... In this care you are right though it would've been simpler to write directly in the object.